# EF 4.1 Many to Many Delete Parent should delete related children

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

EF 4.1 Database First approach.

Say I have this table schema

> Users 1---M UserRoles M---1 Roles

Cascade delete is setup in the Foreign Keys

The UserRoles table has additional columns like CreatedDate so I create a model for UserRoles and map accordingly.

I end up with the following Models:

```
User
----
int Id
string Name
List<UserRoles> UserRoles

UserRoles
---------
int UserId
int RoleId
DateTime CreatedDate
User User
Role Role

Role
----
int Id
string Name
List<UserRoles> UserRoles
```

If I have my configuration correct, should I be able to delete a user and will the user roles rows be deleted WITHOUT having to clear the UserRoles collection manually?

So can I just do this:

```
DbContext.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Deleted;
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Or do I HAVE to do this:

```
user.UserRoles.Clear();
DbContext.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Deleted;
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

My testing shows I HAVE to clear the child collection, but I find conflicting information that if I have cascade delete setup correctly it should work by only deleting the User.

When I DON'T clear the UserRoles I receive this error:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the
>   foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Thanks for you help in clarifying this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use

```
DbContext.Users.Remove(user);
```

It is not the same thing as setting the state to `Deleted`. Setting the state won't mark any child objects with cascading delete setup as `Deleted` but `Remove` will do.

Setting the state to `Deleted` should work **IF** no children are loaded into the context because EF will send only a DELETE statement for the parent to the database and the database will delete the children as well due to the cascading delete in the database.

**IF** however you have loaded children into the context setting the state on the parent to `Deleted` won't set the state of the children. EF will throw the exception, it's not the database who complains.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was going crazy...and yes, the children are loaded which explains why this wasn't worked as expected. They (EF team) ought to change this behavior...seems not very intuitive

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify that deleting a Role or User will in turn delete the child grants. You can use the WillCascadeOnDelete() method on the fluent DbModelBuilder API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoles>
    .HasRequired(d => d.User)
    .WithMany(p => p.UserRoles)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();

modelBuilder.Entity<Role>
    .HasMany(p => p.UserRoles)
    .WithRequired(d => d.Role)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

With this setup, deleting a User or a Role should also delete all of the UserRoles.

Comment: When you say "should" do you mean you have working code that does this?

Comment: Yes, our model is very similar to yours, except that we call the UserRole a "Grant" entity, and we don't expose foreign key properties on it. Also, you have to make sure all of the navigation & collection properties are marked virtual in the POCO's. Though we don't have any code that deletes roles, we do have code that deletes users, and it cascades to the grants because of `WillCascadeOnDelete`.